# Optical Audio Out replacement with passthrough / surround support

Tags: audio, mojave, mac-mini

Can somebody please suggest something to replace the missing optical audio output on the new Macs (Mini 2018)? I have sound cards that support stereo, but I need something which would allow passthrough for surround sound.

I set-up my speakers (Logitech Z906) with my previous Mini (late 2009) via optical link, so I'm looking for some solution that would use the existing wiring (~20m, going around the whole room).

**What I tried:**

- Behringer UCA222 - works out of the box, but only as stereo
- Sweex SC016 - works with the CM6206 enabler, but surround can be set only for the analog ports, SPDIF is stereo. CM6206 datasheet says that it supports passthrough but the system doesn't detect it.
- tried to force passthrough using KODI but got only scrambled noise  (from both SC016 and UCA222)

**What I'm looking for:**

- something that would be recognized as Digital Audio Out by the system (Mojave)
- connected via USB/Thunderbolt
- reasonable price (I don't need any other features, it would be fine if it was just USB dongle with a single S/PDIF out port)

I'm considering Soundblaster X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, but I don't want to end up with another stereo-only sound card in my collection.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: eBay/Amazon has a million cheap generic USB interfaces, to 2.0, 5.1, 7.1, analog or AC3-S/PDIF. The actual technology is as cheap as chips these days - so long as you don't need to actually be able to decode/encode the 5.1 inside the Mac. For some reason, no-one is willing to approach that Patent-minefield.